# Large insert query and "MySQL server has gone away"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have a large(for example 4500 line) **INSERT QUERY** in my **php** code and when this Query want to **execute in mysql** and insert its value, this error occur:

> PDO::exec(): MySQL server has gone away in ...

or

> PDO::exec(): Error reading result set's header

i tried this large query is divided into several small query and execute them but this error occur again.

i know this :

> max_allowed_packet    1048576

but it does not work.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html, and all I needed to do is search for `max_allowed_packet`

Comment: I thought there was a max limit to how many inserts you can do in a single query. Something like 3000

Comment: @apokryfos Nope, its limited to `max_allowed_packet`. So it can be 10k small ones or 100 big ones. Defaults to 4Mb, and I gotta tell you. A 4Mb text file is huge.

Comment: @Xorifelse I have net_buffer_length and max_allowed_packet upgrade. and it does work, thanks for your help.

Comment: Chunk the query into smaller ones. Probably a lot easier to do this than anything else.

Comment: @Xorifelse A 4Mb text file is very very very normal for IIS log files.

Comment: @apokryfos Read: `'i tried this large query is divided into several small query and execute them but this error occur again.'`

Comment: @apokryfos Every time I access the database, it inefficient. The database is like a sleeping giant that is geared up speed slows down. Just like the issue of handle of interrupt in the operating system. The operating system also is like a sleeping giant.

Comment: @MohammadHoseinAbedi I would not know about that, I use Linux. Just checked, my largest log file is 1Mb, after 4 years of not reinstalling using it everyday.

Comment: If you tried with small queries then the error is not from the size but likely a syntax error.

Comment: @apokryfos thanks for your help. i tried this but size of small queries also is large( for example 1000 line). it is not syntax error because this error occur (PDO::exec(): MySQL server has gone away in) not this ( You have an error in your SQL syntax).

Comment: SQL server has gone away can occur from a data error in bulk inserts because if one of them fails the SQL server gives up and "goes away"